# Show JSON data by JSON object Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

When i add this object "Today" then it doesn't print the output(logcat). But i need to use object and show the output. How can i get this data using this object?

**APIService.java**

```
public interface APIService{
@GET("learn/schdeule.json")
Call<List<Schedule>>getScheduleData();
}
```

**GetData Function**

```
public void Get_Data(){
    try {
        final APIService apiService= ApiClient.getClient().create(APIService.class);
        Call<List<Schedule>>call=apiService.getScheduleData();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Schedule>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Schedule>> call, Response<List<Schedule>> response) {

                Log.w("2.0 gson => ",new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response));


                 }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Schedule>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

**JSON Data**

```
{
today: [
{
first_team: "xxx",
second_team: "xxxx",
venue: "xxx",
result: "xxx",
time: "2.47"
},
{
first_team: "xxx",
second_team: "xxxx",
venue: "xxx",
result: "xxx",
time: "2.47"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more...

Comment: yes,  i want to get that json array raw ("today") data in toast message. Basically without that "today" array name, it response ,but with this arrayname,it call onFailure